# WordPress как искать файлы

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Подскажите некий алгоритм как через Chrome, искать файлы Wordpress, допустим на странице есть какой-то элемент к которому привязан Js код. Как лучше всего найти где на хостинге хранится этот код?

Comment: Хмм, могу ошибаться, но вы можете стянуть исходники вашего проекта к себе на локалку. И потом через любое ide выполнить поиск по проекту по ключевым словам.

Comment: Через Chrome - никак. От слова совсем. Вы ни одного файла php та мне увидите. Копия сайта должна быть на локалке, и по ней уже можно с помощью IDE найти всё, что угодно.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, воспользуюсь

Comment: Если js, то в консоли браузера виден путь. Если пхп, то либо искать через панель хостера (если она такое позволяет) или через консль, либо скачивать файлы плагинов и темы и искать в них. Только это навереняка очередная [проблема молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710).

Comment: @SeVlad ок, в следующий раз, буду качественнее формулировать вопрос